# How to include a range in the partition by in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to find the average and stddev for a product price in bigquery.

So I do

```
avg(price) over (partition by model,year)
stddev(price) over (partition by model,year)
```

(where year the year of construction)

what I would like to do (without joining again the table if possible) is the following

```
avg(price) over (partition by model,year±1)
stddev(price) over (partition by model,year±1)
```

for the year to include one year before and after.

thanks in advance,

Comment: what data type your `year` column? give some simple example of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING` in the `OVER()` clause:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST([STRUCT(2010 AS year, 'x' AS model, 2 AS price), (2011, 'x', 4), (2012, 'x', 8), (2013, 'x', 16), (2015, 'x', 32)])
)

SELECT *
  , AVG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY model ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) avg
  , STDDEV(price) OVER(PARTITION BY model ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING ) stddev
FROM data
```

[image]